# How to install payflow pro on the window server 2012

Tags: paypal, asp-classic

We are now moving our classic ASP application on the new server window 2012 R2. We are using Paypal for online transactions. Can you please help us to install correct paypal software  ?

Comment: Shouldn't you look on the PayPal site for such an answer?

Comment: Yes, I looked there but did not found any solution yet.